# How to show the image placeholder smaller than the actual image when using the resizable modifier in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

The following code shows an image inside an Image view, but when there is no image, it displays a placeholder image `"car-placeholder"`. My issue is that when there is no image, the placeholder fills the entire view since I'm using the `.resizable()` modifier, I do want to resize the image but not the placeholder.

```
import SwiftUI

struct NewCarFormView: View {
    
    @State private var inputImage: UIImage?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Spacer()
            Image(uiImage: inputImage ?? UIImage(named: "car-placeholder")!)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .padding(5)
                .border(Color.blue, width: 5)
                .cornerRadius(10)

            Button(action: {
                // show image picker
            }) {
                HStack{
                    Text("Picture")
                    Image(systemName: "camera")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I see with the above code when there is no image...

[image]

And here is what I would like to see when there is no image...

[image]

Again, what I want is to not resize the placeholder but resize the actual image.

Comment: Why are you resizing it, if you don't want it to fill the space? Is there a specific max image width/height you want to constrain?

Comment: If I don't resize it the image doesn't resize and it shows on the entire screen. FYI, the image will be coming from an iPhone. The ideal image size would be 100x100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the nil coalescing operator, use an `if` clause and declare two different paths -- one if the image exists and one if it doesn't. That way, you can apply your modifiers specifically to the image that you intend:

```
struct NewCarFormView: View {
    
    @State private var inputImage: UIImage?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Spacer()
            if let inputImage = inputImage {
                Image(uiImage: inputImage)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .padding(5)
                    .border(Color.blue, width: 5)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            } else {
                VStack {
                    Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "car-placeholder")!)
                }.frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .padding(5)
                    .border(Color.blue, width: 5)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            }

            Button(action: {
                // show image picker
            }) {
                HStack{
                    Text("Picture")
                    Image(systemName: "camera")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could abstract the common modifiers into a separate `ViewModifier` to keep from repeating code:

```
struct MyImageModifiers : ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .padding(5)
            .border(Color.blue, width: 5)
            .cornerRadius(10)
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
struct NewCarFormView: View {
    
    @State private var inputImage: UIImage?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Spacer()
            if let inputImage = inputImage {
                Image(uiImage: inputImage)
                    .resizable()
                    .modifier(MyImageModifiers())
            } else {
                VStack {
                    Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "car-placeholder")!)
                }
                .modifier(MyImageModifiers())
            }

            Button(action: {
                // show image picker
            }) {
                HStack{
                    Text("Picture")
                    Image(systemName: "camera")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```